Next js latest App router font disappearing
I created a next js app with npx create-next@latest
I'm trying to implement fonts into my website and for some reason, when using the app router my fonts disappear.
video: https://youtu.be/5oyzcTSQQrw?si=L16HDphQL6EwWDSb
video steps i did(my mouse was small): refresh(to restart) -> menu -> back to home page -> all fonts are gone
fonts.ts
import {Roboto, Kaushan_Script} from 'next/font/google'

const roboto = Roboto({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  weight: ['400', '700'],
  variable: '--font-roboto',
})

const kaushan = Kaushan_Script({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  weight: ['400'],
  variable: '--font-kaushan',
})



export const robotoVar = roboto.variable
export const kaushanVar = kaushan.variable

home layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import "./globals.css";
import { kaushanVar, robotoVar } from "@/utils/fonts";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Leaf Llama",
  description: "Lettuce eat!",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body
        className={`${robotoVar} ${kaushanVar}`}
      >
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

menu layout.tsx
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";
import { kaushanVar, robotoVar } from "@/utils/fonts";
import '@/app/globals.css'

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${robotoVar} ${kaushanVar}`}>
        <Navbar/>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

tailwind.config.css
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  mode: 'jit',
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        'roboto': ['var(--font-roboto)'],
        'kaushan': ['var(--font-kaushan)']
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
export default config;

Sorry I just pasted lots of code, I literally don't know why my fonts disappear + this is my first time using next js
I also found a possible bug/error? the "body" class name in the layout.tsx disappears when the font disappears
before:
before image
after:
after image
other than than that, I found a band aid solution of deleting the layout.tsx of the menu but I'll need that to place the navbar for all of the other pages I will make
I want a solution to allow fonts with the app router.

first try it in layout itself only one like roboto and remove extended fontFamily from tailwind config for debugging purpose...
if you are not able to solve then let's have a google meet...

It still breaks when I try without tailwind.config. both my layouts are set to just have <body         className={${roboto.className}}       > from const roboto = Roboto({   subsets: ['latin'],   weight: ['400', '700'],   variable: '--font-roboto', }) and the same bug still happens, opening menu then going back to landing page removes fonts. @root_coding
